# JSON Object value in multi dimensional array value (Google GEO Data)

Tags: php, arrays, json, geolocation

All I want is the value long_name for the listing with type postal_code. It's on a different array ID on each address variation otherwise I would have just used semething like this:

```
$jsonobj->results[0]->address_components[2]->long_name;
```

That won't work though ;(

This is the code, from the Google GEO location API

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "2565",
               "short_name" : "2565",
               "types" : [ "postal_code", "postal_code_prefix" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Den Haag",
               "short_name" : "Den Haag",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Den Haag",
               "short_name" : "Den Haag",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Zuid-Holland",
               "short_name" : "ZH",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Nederland",
               "short_name" : "NL",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "2565 Den Haag, Nederland",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
...
```

So, in short, how can i get the "long_name" value for "types == postal_code" (maybe with in_array(postal_code, $types)?).

*Answer already given but wanted to post my version of the function here as well:*

```
$city          = getAddressDetail($jsonobj, 'locality');
$zipcode       = getAddressDetail($jsonobj, 'postal_code');

function getAddressDetail($jsonobj, $attr){
    // Loop over each result
    foreach ($jsonobj->results as $result) {
        // Loop over each address_component of a given result
        foreach ($result->address_components as $component) {
            // Check for 'postal_code' in the types array
            if (in_array($attr, $component->types, true)) {
                // Extract the 'long_name'
                return $component->long_name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _That won't work though_ - why not? are you getting an error?

Comment: Did you use `json_decode($jsonobj, true)` to turn the data from json into an array?

Comment: No Dirk, i use objects. I like that better. 
$jsonobj       = json_decode($curl_response);

Comment: @SeanBright that works for the given value, but like it wrote, for each address the order is different, Google API does return different results for each address (like with ZIP, No ZIP, city only etc.). The sample above would return the City just fine, but next time it may return the zipcde, or house number or else.

Comment: So then I guess you just want to use a foreach loop that loops through `$jsonobj->results[0]->address_components` and for each value it will check if types contains the value postal_code. If it does then you take the long_name value from that element and return it.

Comment: @DirkScholten types itself is also an array, which complicates things. Also, I thought it could be more simple and without a foreach but maybe i am wrong. Sounds like a lot of resources for just a value that is always there (be it in a different key#).

Comment: @KimK. yeah... the way they return the data almost seems 'backwards' for how to access specific data. So to go backwards, you have to loop down into it since postal is not always item [0] as you say. Google must have a reason for this odd output ;) But I cannot see it.

Comment: But the value you want from types is always in [0] from what I can see, so that shouldn't need another loop. Unfortunately I don't see another way to make sure that you're fetching the postal_code apart from looping through them all. 

Don't worry too much about the resources. Foreach loops are very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to nest a few `foreach` loops and then use [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
<?php

// Loop over each result
foreach ($jsonobj->results as $result) {
    // Loop over each address_component of a given result
    foreach ($result->address_components as $component) {
        // Check for 'postal_code' in the types array
        if (in_array('postal_code', $component->types, true)) {
            // Extract the 'long_name'
            echo $component->long_name . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to make the search more generic you could extract into a function:

```
<?php

function find_by_type($obj, $type) {
    $res = [];

    foreach ($obj->results as $result) {
        foreach ($result->address_components as $component) {
            if (in_array($type, $component->types, true)) {
                $res[] = $component->long_name;
            }
        }
    }

    return $res;
}

$res = find_by_type($jsonobj, 'postal_code');

var_dump($res);
```

And if you want to really fancy, pass in a `callable` that will extract the field that you want:

```
function find_by_type($obj, $type, $extractor) {
    $res = [];

    foreach ($obj->results as $result) {
        foreach ($result->address_components as $component) {
            if (in_array($type, $component->types, true)) {
                $res[] = $extractor($component);
            }
        }
    }

    return $res;
}

$res = find_by_type($jsonobj, 'postal_code', function($c) {
    return $c->short_name;
});

var_dump($res);
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. One can always rely on the men of SO with over 50k rep scores :-)
It works well, I'll study it better since it always looks so simple when the result is there, whereas I have been trying all day long haha.

Comment: Haha, just went back here to post my new solution, only to find you have edited your answer and it sort of matches my findings:-). I have made it into a function as well so i can get any resulty back easily now.